Stripe js script violates all the unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' and 'self' directives how it is possible?
Hello I'm trying to integrate stripe payments in my ASP.NET 8 pages project and I get this error despite I allowed the unsafe directives, lack of which could be the reason for the issue but still getting it. Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem? The issue is reporduced both in Chrome and Firefox.
The Error
My code:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src data: https: http:;
 script-src-elem 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'self';
 style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self';" />


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

You should set up the CSP/Content Security Policy directives recommended in the Stripe docs for Stripe.js: https://docs.stripe.com/security/guide?csp=csp-js#content-security-policy


connect-src, https://api.stripe.com, https://maps.googleapis.com
frame-src, https://js.stripe.com, https://hooks.stripe.com
script-src, https://js.stripe.com, https://maps.googleapis.com


For help with your integration beyond that you should contact Stripe support: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Thanks, that helped :). Also had to keep the unsafe-inline. Now its working!

This is the final working code the solution of my question:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
script-src https://js.stripe.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
connect-src https://api.stripe.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
frame-src https://js.stripe.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
style-src https://js.stripe.com  'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />

I had to add unsafe-inline in addition to what was suggested in Stripe documentation.
